# Uploading a Symfony 3.3 project

Tags: php, symfony, web-hosting, symfony-3.3

I finished my symfony project, and bought a hosting and domain. Previously I have uplaoded sites to web, but it was just put everything in *public_html* folder, and the site is running. I tryed this with the project, but it wasn's the case. I'm a bit confused, because at the my storage I had a lot of folders on default. This is how it looks:
[image]
Where should I upload my folders?

Comment: Upload them to "public_html" and set the document root to "pubic_html/web"

Answer (score 1):

Uploading  symfony  is  a little  tricky thing , symfony is  not a  normal  website it's a  big framework

First you need  hosting  with ssh access  ( without it you'll have a lot more problems )

1. create folder symfony on the  same  level that is public_html
2. copy all  your  project  data  , without vendor directory  and composer.lock file
3. login via ssh and

   cd symfony

   composer install

**You shoud always use  composer**  - **because  it 'll check all dependencies with  you php version on server**  (different  libs  and  extensions  may require different  php version and diffent  modules) , and  let  you know  if something  will be not  right.

4. rm public_html folder,  and  create symlink to symfony/web

   ln -s public_html ~/symfony/web
5. upload  sql to database

Comment: Not a bad answer but you should be aware that it is possible to install a Symfony app using ftp access only.  Just a bit tricky.

Comment: Seems that I cannot install composer: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 840957952) (tried to allocate 67108864 bytes) in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 126. I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: try this  php -d memory_limit=-1 composer

Comment: How do I start the project to running? I know server:run is only for localhost

Comment: if you have all  set it should  go as is